# Публикация сайта ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net

При публикации сайта выпадает ошибка

> publish has encountered an error Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object A diagnostic log has been written to following
>   location

Если посмотреть лог

> 5/13/2020 2:38:12 PM System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.InitializeProvider(IVsHierarchy
>   hierarchy)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.CreateViewAsync(IVsHierarchy
>   project, IAsyncServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.ManagedPublishProvider.d__3.MoveNext()

При запуске или сборке проекта ошибок не наблюдается. 
Обновление `VS` не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

Закрыл студию. Изменил название папки `15.0_dcb693eb` по пути
    `C:\Users\R\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio`. Перезапустил студию. Теперь все работает.